# silentLogging in Webdrivers?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to set silent every WebDriver setup Logggings I have in java Selenium tests. 
For example Selenium will log this when setting up the Edge driver:

> [16:21:10.158] - Listening on http://127.0.0.1:42136/
>
> [16:21:10.158] - Listening on http://[::1]:42136/
>
> Mar 05, 2019 4:21:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

By "set-up" I mean:

```
WebDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.EDGE).setup();
WebDriver driver= new EdgeDriver();
```

I found that I can do it on Chrome with this parameter anywhere on my main:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentLogging", "true");
```

But there is no information on Internet about the rest of WebDrivers like:
Edge,
Internet Explorer,
FireFox,
Opera, Safari
etc.

I'm looking for any (all preferently) of these?

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/55011862/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think I have follow the "How do I ask a good question?" guidelines and the question is limited to one problem although that is very subjective. I provided more information and detail for you to get my question, I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm giving an example for the answer to ChromeDriver: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentLogging", "true"); what I was looking for is the same for the other browsers, I don't really understand why space will be a problem. I'm sry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was impossible to me to find a setup that will work for any other driver, but an alternate solution to the main problem is to completely disable the logs in "set-up" time with:

```
System.setOut(
    new PrintStream(new OutputStream() { 
    @Override
    public  void    close() {}
    @Override
    public  void    flush() {}
    @Override
    public  void    write(byte[] b) {}
    @Override
    public  void    write(byte[] b, int off, int len) {}
    @Override
    public  void    write(int b) {}

    }));
System.setErr(
    new PrintStream(new OutputStream() { 
    @Override
    public  void    close() {}
    @Override
    public  void    flush() {}
    @Override
    public  void    write(byte[] b) {}
    @Override
    public  void    write(byte[] b, int off, int len) {}
    @Override
    public  void    write(int b) {}

    }));
```

and then restore them right after.

> The problem with this approach is that it can hide logs of exception
>   of cause other problems related with the time the console loggs are
>   off.