# Hot to suppress EdgeDriver messages from log?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to suppress the logs created from selenium edge driver? Specifically these sorts of log entries:

[17:00:32.066] - Listening on http://127.0.0.1:25321/

I've tried similar ways to the Chrome, Firefox, and IE drivers, but none have the desired outcome.

For example
Chrome...

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Firefox...

```
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/dev/null");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

IE...

```
InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder ieDriverService = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder().withSilent(true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieDriverService.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

During test execution to see lesser logs you could simply pass **--silent** argument to the chromedriver server like this `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentLogging", "true");`.

In edgedriver, you could try the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011862/silentlogging-in-webdrivers). It completely disables the logs in "set-up" time.

For me, I use the `SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation` property under `EdgeDriverService` class. The property is default to **false**. By setting it to **true**, the diagnostics outputs can be suppressed. I use it in C# like this:

```
EdgeDriverService service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var driver = new EdgeDriver(service);
```

The usage in chromedriver is the same. You could refer to [ChromeDriverService Class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriverService.htm) and [EdgeDriverService Class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Edge_EdgeDriverService.htm) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately these properties don't appear to exist for the service class in Java.

Comment: Does the first and the second method in my answer work in Java? Besides, you could refer to [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium#!msg/selenium-users/cwaoAtIPh94/oJkbKIXSCgAJ). It points out that *we would need to basically figure out how to disable INFO level logs from the Java bindings and bump it to show only perhaps WARNING*. And it says this works: `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);`.

Comment: I've not attempted the second method in your response. It doesn't look very clean to me for something that should be rather simple. I already have Chrome, IE and Firefox not showing the logs and I also already have ```java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);``` in my code. It's purely just Edge that is causing me a problem.